# Forgotten the password for my windows mobile phone 1020 dual card

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020

I have forgotten phone password and I cannot enter the phone. 
How do i a hard reset? Please advice. I have tried wrong passwords with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it off and Press power key +vol down for 15sec it will show this(!)sign thete after press vol up then vol down after power button lastly vol down .